# How did they get the shot of the Oahu base in "Snowden"?

Tags: staging

In "Snowden" there is a shot of the interior of the NSA base in Oahu:

[image]

This seems kind of enormous for a staged scene, but it also seems unlikely that the NSA would allow film makers into their base. How did they get this shot?

Comment: Not seen the movie - but what is the purpose of this huge space for a signals intelligence agency? This looks totally more hollywood than reality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you think that looks like the actual base? They don't allow press in there.

According to [this article](https://thecinemaholic.com/where-was-snowden-filmed/):

> The production team chose Bavaria Studios in Munich as one of the filming sites. Olympiapark, in the same city, also doubled as the catacombs. The military drills were shot at Postpalast, Wredestraße 10, whereas the shots with the CIA bunker were captured in Truppenübungsplatz, Bodenwöhr. Furthermore, the lakeside party scene was actually filmed in Evangelische Akademie Tutzing.

When you [look up images of Postpalast](https://www.google.com/search?q=Postpalast%20M%C3%BCnchen&sclient=img&tbm=isch), you'll note it is a round building; I'd imagine that redecorating it could result in it looking like the building in the scene.

---

And after posting [I found this](https://www.dw.com/en/oliver-stones-snowden-film-opens-without-much-ado/a-19554131):

> The catacombs of the city's Olympia Park and the historic Postpalast became the NSA headquarters.

Comment: I don't know for sure either way, but it's not beyond the realms of possibility to build that entirely as a set, even if entire sections are all in CGI. I'm working on a show at the moment with a very similar concept. 3/4 of the cylinder is real with 1/4 open for access. Top, bottom & open 1/4 are bluescreen so they will be seamless CGI in the final image. If you ever hear the call "silver balls" that's a key sign it's going to involve large-scale CGI architecture. [We'd need to know someone who was there, though for confirmation]

Comment: I did just discover, though, that Google has this building marked as 'permanently closed' which does make it *much* more likely they could have used it. I was assuming whoever owned/used it would have to balance their normal usage anainst a production who might have wanted the space for up to 6 months. Being closed certainly frees that requirement up a *long* way. Movie productions *love* abandoned buildings with no other scheduling concerns.

Comment: Ok, I guess the producers just found a really BIG building they could rent.